# Submit to other submit page which submits too and load

Tags: javascript, html, forms, iframe, form-submit

Is it possible to use javascript to submit from page#1 to another page#2 which submits to the iframe within and then load page#2 with submitted results ?

Page#1 search form:

```
<form id="SearchForm" action="http://mysite.com/search-results-jobs/" target="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="search" />
    <input type="hidden" name="listing_type[equal]" value="Job" />
    <label>
        <strong>What?</strong> 
        <em><input type="text" value="job title, keywords or company name" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='job title, keywords or company name'" onFocus="if(this.value =='job title, keywords or company name' ) this.value=''" name="keywords [all_words]" /></em>
    </label>
    <label>
        <strong class="color">Where?</strong>
        <b><input type="text" value="city, state or zip code"  onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='city, state or zip code'" onFocus="if(this.value =='city, state or zip code' ) this.value=''" name="City[all_words]" /></b>
    </label>
    <a href="#" class="SearchForm-link" onclick="document.getElementById('SearchForm').submit()"/>Search</a>
</form>
```

Page#2

```
<form id="SearchForm" action="http://mysite.com/search-results-jobs/" target="my-iframe" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="search" />
    <input type="hidden" name="listing_type[equal]" value="Job" />
    <label>
        <strong>What?</strong>
        <em><input type="text" value="job title, keywords or company name" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='job title, keywords or company name'" onFocus="if(this.value =='job title, keywords or company name' ) this.value=''" name="keywords[all_words]" /></em></label>
    <label>
        <strong class="color">Where?</strong>
        <b><input type="text" value="city, state or zip code" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='city, state or zip code'" onFocus="if(this.value =='city, state or zip code' ) this.value=''" name="City[all_words]" /></b>
    </label>
    <a href="#" class="SearchForm-link" onclick="one(); two(); three(); four();">Search</a>
    <input type="submit" id="btn-search" class="button" value="Cauta"/>
</form>
<iframe id="my-iframe" name="my-iframe" align="right" src="http://mysite.com" frameborder="0" height="100%" scrolling="no" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? Maybe show us some mock up code?

Comment: Here are the test page1 http://itmjobs.ro/lidl/page1.html and page2 http://itmjobs.ro/lidl/page2.html  All I need is when search on page#1 to load page#2 with results in iframe. Right now if you search on page#1 it loads iframe result page alone while I need to load page#2 with iframe results.

Comment: I haven't ever worked with iframes before, but it seems like it should be pretty easy with the right sort of window.onload function in page2.  Do just as you've indicated.  Have page1 load to page2, and then have a window.onload in page2 that loads the iframe.  What is the difficulty?